# Asp radio buttons is not calling javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, radio-button

I am working on using asp :radio buttons. I am trying to use 2 radio buttons so that if any one of them is selected then other will be unchecked. I am calling JavaScript function on change event of these buttons. That function will add some values and return the out put in the textboxes.I tried to use normal asp buttons then switch to radio button groups and now trying radio button list. need to call javascript function on radio button change event.These buttons will checked and unchecked but java script function is not returning correct values. I guess there are some naming conventions which are not correct or something is not working . looking forward for help to fix this. Neither one of these 3 way is working.

My test.aspx file contains

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="span2">Test Career:</div>
                <div class="span8">
                <asp:RadioButton ID="TestCareerList" runat="server" clientmode=Static Text="MasterDegree">
```

```
                </div>
           </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Document.ready function in aspx page

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("input:radio").click(function () 
{
updateYears();
}
}

javascript function is:

    function updateYears() {
        var yrsDocTemp = parseFloat(yrsDoc);
        var yrsMastTemp = parseFloat(yrsMast);


        if ($("ContentPlaceHolder2_drpEmplClass").val() != "" && $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_StudentCareerList]").SelectedValue!= "") {
            var updateValue = 0;

            //Get EmplCalss
            if ($("#ContentPlaceHolder2_drpEmplClass").val() == "GA") {
                updateValue = updateValue + 1;
            }
            else if ($("#ContentPlaceHolder2_drpEmplClass").val() == "GAF" || $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_drpEmplClass").val() == "GAP") {
                updateValue = updateValue + .5;
            }


            if ($("#ContentPlaceHolder2_Career").Text =="DoctoralDegree")
                {
                yrsDocTemp = yrsDocTemp + updateValue;
            }

            else if ($("#ContentPlaceHolder2_Career").Text == "MastersDegree") {

                yrsMastTemp = yrsMastTemp + updateValue;
            }

        }

        //Update the fields
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_drpYearsDoctoral").val(yrsDocTemp);
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_drpYearsMasters").val(yrsMastTemp);
    }

I am calling this function under document.ready function like this-



    $("input:RadioButtonList[ID=^TestCareerList").change(function(){
                    updateYears();
                });

                $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_drpEmplClass").change(function () {
                    updateYears();
                });


When I debug the javascript code I see the names of buttons have been changed.

    <tr>
                <td>
                <input id="ContentPlaceHolder2_TestCareerList_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder2$TestCareerList" value="MastersDegree" />
                <label for="ContentPlaceHolder2_TestCareerList_0">Master</label>
                </td>
                <td><input id="ContentPlaceHolder2_TestCareerList_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder2$TestCareerList" value="DoctoralDegree" />
                <label for="ContentPlaceHolder2_TestCareerList_1">Doctoral</label>
                </td>
    </tr>

    Kindly looking for help.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is trying to bind to your *server-side* elements:

```
$("input:RadioButtonList[ID=^TestCareerList")
```

But JavaScript has no knowledge of the server-side code.  It only operates on the client-side code.  And, as you've noticed, your client-side HTML is different.  So your JavaScript needs to target *that* code.  Something like this:

```
$("input:radio[ID=*TestCareerList")
```

The same would be true for any other selectors you have.  As you're discovering, WebForms controls are famously *not great* for finely controlling your client-side code.  ASP.NET MVC makes this a lot easier, but may be a pretty fundamental shift for what you're doing.

One thing that may help is setting your `ClientID` property on some controls to `Static`.  Take care when doing this however and debug your HTML accordingly, because if you end up with repeated `id` values in your HTML then it's invalid and the behavior of the JavaScript when selecting on that `id` would be undefined.

Comment: Do i need to just change javascript function. with the line you mentioned. Or do i need to add some wildcard characters as name of the controls are changing at server side. what about the aspx code  is there any problem?

Comment: @user2897967: Overall it's pretty broad, but the heart of the problem is that you need your jQuery selectors to target your HTML, not your server-side ASP.NET code.  As for "is there any problem" that would depend on whether or not you're observing any kind of problem.  It's certainly possible that there's more than one error in your code, but the one identified here is one for you to fix first.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.Nope it didn't work.

Comment: @user2897967: Define "didn't work".  What's the updated HTML?  What's the updated JavaScript?  In what specific way does it fail?

Comment: @user2897967: Which change event?  Is the event bound to any elements in the first place?  Again, what is the updated code?  You need to provide at least *some* information about the problem.

Comment: i replaced code with your code didn't work Then i modfied code again. event is radio bttn change event

Comment: @user2897967: Your code is trying to call a function named "updateYearsFunding", but you don't define any such function.  You can only call functions that exist.  Surely the developer console in your browser is telling this error.  When you're trying to debug a problem in your browser, I recommend actually looking at the debugging tools.